# How to replace column values with dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
 A     B
 one   six
 two   seven
 three level
 five  one
```

and a dictionary

```
my_dict={1:"one,two",2:"three,four"}
```

I want to  replace df.A with my_dict keys().

My desired output is,

```
 A     B
 1     six
 1     seven
 2     level
 five  one
```

I tried `df.A.replace(my_dict,regex=True)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need dict comprehension for separate each values to keys first:

```
my_dict={1:"one,two",2:"three,four"}
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in my_dict.items() for k in oldv.split(',')}
print (d)
{'one': 1, 'three': 2, 'four': 2, 'two': 1}

df.A = df.A.replace(my_dict)
```

Comment: Any other way without modyfing the dictionary ?

Comment: @pyd - Unfortunately I have no another idea, but in my opinion not.

Comment: @pyd - Glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution via `map` / `fillna`:

```
d = {v_i: k for k, v in my_dict.items() for v_i in v.split(',')}
df['A'] = df['A'].map(d).fillna(df['A'])

#       A      B
# 0     1    six
# 1     1  seven
# 2     2  level
# 3  five    one
```